# How to write function for onclick in mvc 2 application

Tags: model-view-controller

Please help me ... I don't know how to write event for button. I placed button in the mvc 2 aspx file that i created.  
i want to write function to do some thing when the button is clicked.

Comment: sorry for my language. If i did wrong in either posting the question or answering the qusetion please notify the mistakes. I am new to this stackoverflow aswell to asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult EvaluvateStudent(FormCollection collection)
        {
            Model.StudentModels studentDetail = new Model.StudentModels();
            studentDetail.Name = collection["Name"];
            studentDetail.RegNo = Convert.ToInt32(collection["RegNo"]);
            studentDetail.Tamil = Convert.ToSingle(collection["Tamil"]);
            studentDetail.English = Convert.ToSingle(collection["English"]);
            studentDetail.Total = CalculateTotal(studentDetail.Tamil, studentDetail.English);
            ViewData["Total"] = studentDetail.Total;
            return View("Student");
        }
        public float CalculateTotal(float tamil,float english)
        {
            float total = tamil + english;
            return total;
        }
```